# How to scroll treeview1 with vscrollbar (devexpress)

Tags: c#, vb.net, treeview, devexpress

How to scroll Treeview1 (System.Windows.Forms.TreeView) with vscrollbar1 of devexpress?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I am using treeview of windows and I want to replace its default scrollbar with devexpress's vscrollbar.

Comment: @iProgramIt, the first question should be why I am using default tree view instead of tree list (devexpress). Because I could not find a way to set image in front of nodes. that's I decided to use to default treeview and to give to fancy look I am trying to use vscrollbar of devexpress instead of default scrollbar.